IF element IN list in robot framework
I am trying to see if the element is present in the list using robot framework this is my test.
IF   Calgary    IN   ${list}
     do something
END

but I am getting this error "No keyword with name 'IN' found"

it uses Python 'in' so it should be like this
IF classic in ${list}


Yes the IN i«s only used for FOR data selection.

You can also do this by using List Should Contain Value built-in function. This built-in function checks whether the value exists in the given list and if it fails, it shows the msg(if you do not pass msg, it shows a default error).
List Should Contain Value    list_    value

Example:
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
*** Variables ***
@{list}    Toronto    Vancouver    Calgary

*** Test Cases ***
check
    List Should Contain Value   ${list}    Calgary    msg=The item not found

